# Breakpoints in InProc COM object .dll?

Tags: breakpoint, com

I have a very simple exe that just uses CoCreateInstance to load a COM dll.  This dll contains 1 function.  I know where it is, I know what it's called etc.  I know where in the exe it calls it.  But I am unable to set a breakpoint that triggers using either IDA 7, or OllyDbg 1.1 or 2.0.  Anyone have any tips for getting a functioning breakpoint inside a COM dll?

Comment: May be it is not possible because in COM realm the caller does not know where the implemented dll is. All parameters are marshaled through COM. Either use `GetProcAddress()` or find the function in COM dll in any disassembler.